# Android Bound Services and MVP Design Patterns?

Tags: android, android-service, mvp, android-service-binding

I am relatively new to Android development, and as of late I have been reading looking at the MVP architecture in Android. I would like to start implementing it in my projects, primarily for the decoupling and testing benefits it provides.

Right now I am working on a project that is using Intent Services to make GET and POST REST calls to an API. It uses ResultReceivers to pack the results of the calls (data, errors, etc.) directly to the Activity/Fragment. I would like to refactor this but I am still unsure how to proceed.

I would like to use a BoundService since the user can make multiple calls while the activity is in the foreground and I think it is a cleaner approach to have the model class use the interface exposed by the BoundService. However, since the BoundService is making a network call, I have to make the call off the UI Thread (e.g. using an AsyncTask). This is where I am stuck more than anything. Where does the Async Task belong? The presenter needs to handle and respond to different errors/exceptions and call the appropriate view methods for each scenario. I was thinking of creating some sort of wrapper class to interrogate for exceptions/errors in the AsyncTask's onPostExecute() method, but I was also thinking this sort of problem has probably come up for others before, hence this question.

Does anyone have any suggestions for a ***pure*** Android solution for this? Any suggestions or advice you can provide me? I have searched online and I am finding a hard time. Most of the ones I find do not have examples of making network calls, and if they do, they use 3rd party libraries.

Answer (score -3):

You can also use this as an excellent library [Retrofit2](http://square.github.io/retrofit/)

And not to invent a bicycle

Comment: Thanks for your response but I am specifically looking at how Services can be used in MVP pattern. Since we cannot invoke a network call on the main thread, we need to use some other mechanism to do so. Where that mechanism (e.g. AsyncTask) lives in MVP is where I could use some direction or references in terms of MVP patterns